# Creating summary class from different sources

Tags: c#, wcf, class

Im trying to build a business logic for my project. The project uses 4 different WCF souces which all provides the similar products. And I want to implement a product that cover that 4 product for example:

```
class WCF1.Product {
    string Name;
    int ID;
    string Image;
    string Brand;
}

class WCF2.ProductDetail {
    string ProductName;
    int Identity;
    string Photo;
    string Color;
}

class WCF3.ProductInfo {
    string Name;
    int ID;
    string Image;
}

class WCF4.Product {
    string ProductName;
    int Identity;
    string Photo;
    double Weight;
}
```

At least i want to have

```
class Product {
    string Name;
    int ID;
    string Photo;
    string Brand;
    string Color;
    double Weight;
}
```

On the both classes ID or Identify is representing the unique ID of each product. So how can i have such that summary or cover class from all source classes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you replacing the 4 classes with this one?  Would a [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Guid(v=vs.110).aspx) be helpful?

Comment: @Harrison on each WCF class ID or Identity already unique, i need to create final class from these 4 classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just hand map it?

```
public class ProductBO
{
    Product GetProduct(int ID)
    {
        // make service calls against the ID and populate DTOs from services
        WCF1.Product p1 = new WCF1.Product();
        WCF2.Product p2 = new WCF2.Product();
        WCF3.Product p3 = new WCF3.Product();
        WCF4.Product p4 = new WCF4.Product();

        p1 = WCF1.GetProduct(ID);
        p2 = WCF2.GetProduct(ID);
        p3 = WCF3.GetProduct(ID);
        p4 = WCF4.GetProduct(ID);

        // then map each to your domain Product object
        Product p = new Product();
        p.Name = p1.Name;
        p.ID = ID;
        p.Color = p2.Color;
        p.Brand = p1.Brand;
        p.Photo = p2.Photo;
        p.Weight = p4.Weight;

        return p;
    }
}
```

I didn't take into account any differences between Name, Photo/Image, etc. but if they are different then you'd need to consider which WCF source to use, concatenate, etc.

Comment: Yeah i think i should map the classes with the needed case. Thanks